# reducing a list of objects using methods within the objects

Tags: python

I have a list of `ChromosomeInterval` objects which have the method `union`. I want to apply this method sequentially to each member of the list. I want to do this with `reduce`, using a `lambda`. However, when I do so, I have the error below:

```
>>> result
[ChromosomeInterval('1', 0, 0, '+'), ChromosomeInterval('1', 8, 10, '+'), ChromosomeInterval('1', 10, 10, '+')]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), result)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'union'
```

But if I change the `union` to the classic `+` operator usage of `reduce`, I get the error I would expect because `ChromosomeInterval` does not have a `__add__` method:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, result)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ChromosomeInterval' and 'ChromosomeInterval'
```

What is the difference between these two? Why does the call to `union` operate on a `list` but the call to `+` operators on the `ChromosomeInterval` objects?

Comment: What does `union` return? A `ChromosomeInterval` or a list? `+` seems to fail on the first pair, and `union` fails on the second pair, trying to call `union` on a list that seems to be the result of the first call.

Comment: Ah you are right, that is the problem! union can return a `list` in the case where there is no way to collapse the region, as is the case for the interval [0,0] and [8,10]